# lost auth state when page refresh in reactjs hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

When i login with valid credentials server send JWT to browser i store this JWT in localstore page redirect to home page everything works fine and in home page i have loadUser function which send request to server to get the user details of valid user but when i refresh the page it home page never execute because auth state returns to false and page redirect from home to login page
This is App.js

```js
 import React, { Fragment } from "react";
        import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
         import Navbar from "./components/layout/Navbar";
       import Home from "./components/pages/Home";
        import Login from "./components/auth/Login";
        import PrivateRoute from "./components/routing/PrivateRoute";
      import "./App.css";
       const App = () => {
      return (
            <AuthState>
              <Router>
            <Fragment>
              <Navbar />
              <div className="container">
                <Alerts />
                <Switch>
                  <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Home} />
                  <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
                </Switch>
              </div>
            </Fragment>
          </Router>
         </AuthState>
  );
};
export default App;
```

This is my authsate code from where my state changes after successful login

```
import React, { useReducer } from "react";
    import axios from "axios";
    import AuthContext from "./authContext";
    import authReducer from "./authReducer";
    import {
      USER_LOADED,
      AUTH_ERROR,
      LOGIN_SUCCESS,
      LOGIN_FAIL,
      } from "../types";
    const AuthState = props => {
      const initialState = {
          isAuthenticated: null,
          user: null,
      };
      const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(authReducer, initialState);
      // Load User
      const loadUser = async () => {
        if (localStorage.token) {
          setAuthToken(localStorage.token);
        }
        try {
          const res = await axios.get("/api/auth");
          dispatch({ type: USER_LOADED, payload: res.data });
        } catch (err) {
          dispatch({ type: AUTH_ERROR });
        }
      };
      // Login User
      const login = async formData => {
        const config = {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          }
        };
        try {
          const res = await axios.post("api/auth", formData, config);
          dispatch({
            type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
            payload: res.data
          });
          loadUser();
        } catch (err) {
          dispatch({
            type: LOGIN_FAIL,
            payload: err.response.data.msg
          });
        }
      };
      return (
        <AuthContext.Provider
          value={{
                  isAuthenticated: state.isAuthenticated,
              user: state.user,
              loadUser,
            login,
         }}
        >
          {props.children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
      );
    };
    export default AuthState;
```

This is reducer code authReducer.js

```
import {
  USER_LOADED,
  AUTH_ERROR,
  LOGIN_SUCCESS,
  LOGIN_FAIL,
    } from "../types";
   export default (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case USER_LOADED:
      return {
        ...state,
        isAuthenticated: true,

        user: action.payload
      };
       case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
      localStorage.setItem("token", action.payload.token);
      return {
        ...state,
          isAuthenticated: true
         };
       case AUTH_ERROR:
    case LOGIN_FAIL:
         localStorage.removeItem("token");
      return {
        ...state,

        isAuthenticated: false,
           user: null,
         };
         default:
      return state;
  }
};

This is private route
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import AuthContext from "../../context/auth/authContext";

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  const authContext = useContext(AuthContext);
  const { isAuthenticated, loading } = authContext;
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        !isAuthenticated && !loading ? (
          <Redirect to="/login" />
        ) : (
          <Component {...props} />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

Comment: Mostly for the authentication or authorization purpose

Comment: the code shown doesn't seem related to your issue. Can you show us where the localstorage is set and used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's to be expected.

If you want to persist the token you should save it in `localStorage` or a `cookie`.

Then, you should check for the token existence and validity in `componentDidMount` or in an `useEffect` (with a void dependency array) if you are using `hooks`.

It'd be nice if you could show us where you are making `AJAX` requests because if, for example, you are using `Axios` you can encapsulate this logic in a `request` interceptor.

Comment: let me know if you need more info

Comment: Any solution to this problem? I am having the same issue and still had my question unanswered also.

Comment: LocalStorage and Cookie are vulnerable to XSS and CSRF attacks. How do you prevent that?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the JSON web token which is used for user authentication/authorization. Can you give us more information about this?

Comment: let me know if you need more info